# Iterate through URLs

Tags: bash, loops, ffmpeg

If I wanted to use ffmpeg to download a bunch of .ts files from a website, and the url format is

```
http://example.com/video-1080Pxxxxx.ts
```

Where the `xxxxx` is a number from 00000 to 99999 (required zero padding), how would I iterate through that in bash so that it tries every integer starting at 00000, 00001, 00002, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Loop over the integer values from `0` to `99999`, and use `printf` to pad to 5 digits.

```
for x in {0..99999}; do
    zx=$(printf '%05d' $x)  # zero-pad to 5 digits
    url="http://example.com/video-1080P${zx}.ts"
    ...  # Do something with url
done
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm geeking out over this!

Answer (score 0):

In pure bash:

```
$ n=99999 ; for ((i=0; i<=n; i++)) { s=$(printf "%05d" $i); echo $s ; }
```

or with a utility:

```
$ seq -w 0 99999
$ seq --help

Usage: seq [OPTION]... LAST
  or:  seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
  or:  seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
Print numbers from FIRST to LAST, in steps of INCREMENT.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -f, --format=FORMAT      use printf style floating-point FORMAT
  -s, --separator=STRING   use STRING to separate numbers (default: \n)
  -w, --equal-width        equalize width by padding with leading zeroes
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not get do something with a for loop:

```
for i in 0000{0..9} 000{10..99} 00{100..999} 0{1000..9999} {10000..99999}
do
    # Curl was used since some minimal installs of linux do not have wget
    curl -O http://example.com/video-1080P"$i".ts 
    sleep 1
done
```

(I am sure that there is a much better way to do this but it is not presenting itself to me at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

My Bash (4.3) can do this:

```
$ echo {001..010}
001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010
```

So you could just do

```
for i in {00000..99999}; do
    url="http://example.com/video-1080P${i}.ts"
    # Use url
done
```